# Use SAML to add Windows Credentials to ADFS

Tags: c#, .net, token, saml, adfs

I am wondering how to pass a token with the user's Windows Login details (username, password) to the ADFS and allow them to avoid typing in the same details again. I am unsure what is the best method to accomplish this.

Comment: If your users use Internet Explorer, this should work automatically (when the ADFS server is in the intranet zone). With other browsers, I think there is no way to achieve that.

Comment: Cheers for giving me this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure of your question but it sounds like you want SSO between a SAML application and other .NET applications.

If that's the case, ADFS does this out the box.

If you configure your SAML and other applications as RP with ADFS, you will have SSO across all of them.

Comment: Apologies for the badly written question I was in a rush when I write it. Thanks for the speedy response. I will give this a go.